# DGrid: Fit column to data

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have am using a DGrid like this:

```
var dgrid = new OnDemandGrid({
    store: myStore,
    columns: [
        {field: "name"},
        {field: "age"}
    ],
    showHeader: false
},divName);
dgrid.startup();
```

It is currently sizing itself like this:

[image]

I would like the first column sized to fit the longest piece of data:

[image]

If the longest name were removed from the store the first row should resize itself like this:

[image]

[I have created a JSFiddle with a DGrid as a template for answers.](http://jsfiddle.net/WgaVg/7/)

---

Edit: I have see the [Sitepen article](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/05/03/css-styling-of-dgrid/) on sizing DGrid but it doesn't mention how to resolve this.

Edit2: Someone asking the same question on [another forum](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/102060-Dynamic-column-sizing-dgrid-%28fit-content%29).

Comment: Why not make use of `min-width` in `CSS`? It will maintain the `min-width` when content is less than it and expand to fit the content in case content is more than the width.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `min-width` in `CSS`. It will maintain the `min-width` when content is less than it and expand to fit the content in case content is more than the width.

You can make use of it as such:

```
div {
    vertical-align:top;
}

.Container {
    border:1px solid Black;
}

.name {
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    min-width:100px;
}

.number {
    display:inline-block;
    height:150px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
}
```

You can see this here->http://jsfiddle.net/q9Vtx/2/

See that the min-width property lets the content 'fit in'.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I am not sure how this is going to help.  In order to use `min-width` the way you are proposing I would need to know what the min width of something was going to be.  I guess that I may be able to keep track of that, but it seems like a major hassle.  What I would really like is some property on the DGrid object to say - make column minimum.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude You don't need to know the `min-width` at all. Keep a **very low** `min-width` say 50px or 20px . Whenever your content is more than the specified min-width,  browser will ensure that the container always expands enough to fit the content completly. **The trick here is** that since your `min-width` is going to be so low, that your browser would end up doing this always. Hence, essentially, your container would be as dynamic as your content!!

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude You don't need to assign an arbitrary `min-width` at all. Just keep it low enough so that the width of the content is always greater than this min-width. I hope you get the point.

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude Just to illustrate this point, see this fiddle here-> http://jsfiddle.net/q9Vtx/4/. See that the content has a min-width of just 15px (you can reduce it further as well). Yet, you see every box is 're-adjusted' to fit in the content.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle.  I see what you did with inline-blocks.  That is a cool way to build a similar kind of layout.  Unfortunately I am using a DGrid (and can't break from that - I need the auto-update, selection, etc functionality).  I created a JSFiddle, if you want to try applying CSS to it you can find it here:http://jsfiddle.net/WgaVg/6/